# Issue in Dynatree Embed in forms Example

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, dynatree

I am trying to implement dynatree embed in forms example given on [this website.](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html)

This is the script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#tree").dynatree({
        checkbox: true,
        selectMode: 3,
        onSelect: function(select, node) {
    // Display list of selected nodes
    var selNodes = node.tree.getSelectedNodes();
    // convert to title/key array
    var selKeys = $.map(selNodes, function(node){
         return "[" + node.data.key + "]: '" + node.data.title + "'";
    });
    $("#echoSelection4").text(selKeys.join(", "));
  },


            // In real life we would call a URL on the server like this:
//          initAjax: {
//              url: "/getTopLevelNodesAsJson",
//              data: { mode: "funnyMode" }
//              },
            // .. but here we use a local file instead:
            initAjax: {
                url: "sample-data3.json",
                data: { mode: "funnyMode" }
                },
            onActivate: function(node) {
                $("#echoActive").text(node.data.title);
            },
            onDeactivate: function(node) {
                $("#echoActive").text("-");
            }
        });
        $("form").submit(function() {
  // Serialize standard form fields:
  var formData = $(this).serializeArray();

  // then append Dynatree selected 'checkboxes':
  var tree = $("#tree").dynatree("getTree");
  formData = formData.concat(tree.serializeArray());

  // and/or add the active node as 'radio button':
  if(tree.getActiveNode()){
    formData.push({name: "activeNode", value: tree.getActiveNode().data.key});
  }

  alert("POSTing this:\n" + jQuery.param(formData));

  $.post("<?php echo APP_URL;?>admin/submit_data.php",
       formData,
       function(response, textStatus, xhr){
         alert("POST returned " + response + ", " + textStatus);
       }
  );
  return false;
});


    });
</script>
```

And inside `<body>` tag :

```
<form>
Username: <input type="text" name="userName" />
<br>
<textarea name="comment"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb1" value="foo" checked> Foo
<input type="radio" name="rb1" value="bar"> Bar
<input type="radio" name="rb1" value="baz"> Baz
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="John" checked>John
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="Paul">Paul
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="George">George
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="Ringo">Ringo
<br>

<!-- The name attribute is used by tree.serializeArray()  -->
<div id="tree" name="selNodes">
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Send data">
```

And in submit_data.php i have

```
print_r($_POST);
```

When i select more than one nodes and click on send data the data is posted to submit_data.php. When i check the post parameters under console tab through firebug, i am getting following data.

```
 comment    test
 rb1    foo
 selNodes   restaurant1
 selNodes   screen1
 selNodes   screen2
 selNodes   screen3
 userName   gaurav
```

But `print_r($_POST)` prints following data:

```
 Array
(
[userName] => gaurav
[comment] => test
[rb1] => foo
[cb1] => John
[selNodes] => screen3
)
```

Ideally i should get all the values of selNodes. But according to my understanding since parameter name is same that is selNodes for all the nodes that's why i am getting only one value.

How do i get all the values?

Comment: I don't know much about PHP, but if you have the same problem when you select more than one checkbox ('cb1'), it's not a problem with dynatree. Maybe you should try $HTTP_POST_VARS["selNodes"] (just guessing from some google results)?

Comment: Sorry, $HTTP_POST_VARS seems to be deprecated, $_POST should be it

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about PHP, but some checkbox samples on the web append braces to the element name in order to pass arrays:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1[]" value="John" checked>John
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1[]" value="Paul">Paul
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1[]" value="George">George
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1[]" value="Ringo">Ringo
```

So you could try

```
<div id="tree" name="selNodes[]">
</div>
```

Comment: ``name="selNodes[]"`` in tree definition did the trick. And in php you can read values as array. Thank you very much